# 1-D Conduction Steady state heat transfer using FD

Tags: finite-difference, iterative-method

I have tried to solve 1-D Conduction Steady state heat transfer problems in Matlab (see below).

**Here is the 1-D model:**

```
T''[x] == 0, T[0] == 100, T'[100] == 0
```

**Analytical Solution:**

```
T[x] = 100 for x: [0, 100]
```

I am so suprised that so many iterations (**2,500,000**) are required for a correct solution (here:T=100 for every node)...

***Is it true that we need so many iterations for such a very simple ODEs using FD? Or?***

**Update:**

**@ConvexHull**: the numerical solution is equal to the analytical solution if k = 2,500,000 is used. (Just run it )

*The 1-D Conduction Steady state heat transfer in Matlab code looks like:*

```
clc
clear all

L=100;
N=1000;
dx=L/(N-1);

T = zeros(N,1);
Tb = 100; % initial temperature

k = 1500000;
T(1,1)=Tb;


for j=1:k
       
    for i=2:N-1
        
        T(i,1)=(T(i+1,1)+T(i-1,1))/2;
        
    end
    
    T(N,1) = T(N-1,1);
    

end

 xx= 0:dx:L;
 plot(xx,T)
 ylim([0 100])
```

Comment: I can't see in your code any division with the time step $k$

Comment: Also, what is in mathematical terms, the equation ( +bc) that you have to solve?

Comment: The updating of T seems suspicious as you overwrite the previous iterate and read from the next iterate's value.  That is, T is always in an inconsistent state and you probably want a buffer to store the next state.  The finite difference stencil, treatment of boundary conditions, and choice of iterative method are also suspicious.  Without the equations provided, though, it's hard to provide a proper answer.

Comment: According to your code, your problem appears to have Dirichlet BC at the left and Neumann BC at the right, but I would suggest that you add the equation and BC in mathematical form. Also, you are using Jacobi iteration to solve the problem and this method might present slow convergence.

Comment: On a second look, it looks like Gauss–Seidel is being used as the linear solver so the inconsistent updating of T is probably ok

Comment: @andereBen as mentioned, it is a steady state problem ... we do not need time step t ...

Comment: @StevenRoberts it has been updated, it takes too long, how can we reduce the computational iterations?

Comment: @YSVSDVXCVXCV sorry you're right, I red too fast.

Comment: @YSVSDVXCVXCV There are two main problems in your code. 1. You are using the wrong FD stencil. 2. You have to consider dx. You can improve speed by using the SOR method instead of Jakobi or Gauss-Seidel method.

Comment: @ConvexHull  1.) why are you sure that I am using the wrong FD stencil for such a simple ode? what is the correct FD stencil in your option? 2.) To note that I just use 999 elements  (1000 nodes) for 1D ODE, therefore, dx is fully ok. Or?

Comment: @YSVSDVXCVXCV Your $dx$ depends on $L$ and $N$ and so does your FD stencil. Your stencil looks ok, i was a little to fast, however $dx$ is missing.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it cancels.